# bootstrap selectpicker dynamic select not posting selected value

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I have two bootstrap selectpickers, of which one is dynamically filled with options based on the first.  That part seems to be working properly, however, the selected option of the second isn't getting set when I post the form.  It just keeps the first item in the list selected no matter what you select.

I've used the selectpicker.refresh() so that the values are filled in the select correctly.   Here is my code that I fill the dynamic select with:

```
jQuery("#field_c7vkw42").empty(); //To reset courts
jQuery("#field_c7vkw42").append("<option value=''>--Select--</option>");
jQuery(arr).each(function(i) { //to list counties
jQuery("#field_c7vkw42").append("<option value=\"" + arr[i].value +  "\">" + arr[i].display + "</option>")
jQuery('#field_c7vkw42').selectpicker('refresh');
```

If you'd like to see the live form https://funnydriving.com/aaabbb/ and it's on step 2 where you choose the court.  Right now I have it to validate, so you will see no matter what you select it thinks it's empty?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I believe I finally found out what was going on, in case anyone has this issue in the future.  It turns out that jquerybootstrapvalidation.js ( http://ReactiveRaven.github.com/jqBootstrapValidation) has functionality to clear out any old helper message boxes upon form submission:

```
//for remove old error helpblock start
$inputs.each(function (i, el) {
var $this = $(el),
$controlGroup = $this.parents(".control-group").first(),
$helpBlock = $controlGroup.find(".help-block").first();             
$this.trigger('change');
```

Which as you can see was triggering the "change" on each of the form elements.  This essentially was reseting my second dynamic box because it was thinking a change was made to the first select.